# Generate PDF from set of JPEGs

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a set of JPEG's on my server all the same size.  Can I  convert this into a PDF file server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using iText for this requirement

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(yourOutFile));
document.open();

for(int i=0;i<numberOfImages;i++){
  Image image1 = Image.getInstance("myImage"+i+".jpg");
  image1.scalePercent(23f);
  document.newPage();
  document.add(image1);
}
document.close();
```

Comment: To make this work for me, what do I need?  (What libraries to include?)

Comment: @anu I'm getting the following errors:" does not contain a definition
for 'getInstance" I have already add and imported the iText Library using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp;

Comment: @illDev Full stack trace of the problem is required. I am a Java programmer and I guess iTextSharp is for C#, so why dont you post a new question, with a link to this post.

Answer (score 3):

I'd try using http://www.pdfsharp.net/

Something along the lines of

```
PdfPage page = outputDocument.AddPage();
page.Size = PdfSharp.PageSize.A4;
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
XImage image = XImage.FromFile("MyJPGFileXXX.jpg");
gfx.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I usually use iText Sharp, but I'm looking into trying this library, it appears pretty easy to use.

Comment: mdmulinax, pls see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437706/pdf-from-bitmap I'm getting distort pdf when I use PDFSharp

Answer (score 2):

[DotImage](http://www.atalasoft.com) has built-in classes to do this.  If all your jpegs are in one folder, you can do this:

```
FileSystemImageSource source = new FileSystemImageSource(pathToDirectory, "*.jpg", true);
PdfEncoder encoder = new PdfEncoder();
using (FileStream outstm = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create)) {
    encoder.Save(outstm, source, null);
}
```

Which will stream all of the images ending with .jpg into an output PDF file.  Each page will be fit to the size of the image (this is settable).  As far as I know, there is no practical limit to the number of pages you can encode (I'm pretty sure you will exceed the PDF limit before you exhaust your heap memory).  In testing, I've run hundreds of images through it without stressing the machine.

Compression can be controlled with an event if you want finer control (ie, JPEG compression level or using Flate or JPEG 2000).  Color profiles will be included if present in the JPEG and if you want PDF/A-1b, it will do that too.  There is also some basic support for setting up a table of contents, if you want.

Disclaimer - I work for Atalasoft and personally wrote the FileSystemImageSource and PdfEncoder classes (as well as nearly all the underlying PDF generation tools).

Comment: What language are you writing in, and what libraries are you using?  (i.e. What do I need in order to work this program?)

Comment: Is it possible to use DotImage to generate the PDF from jpegs that are not saved on the file directory (eg. for files in a database). So instead of FileSystemImageSource, is there like a MemoryStreamImageSource or something that allows me to feed it a stream to output into a PDF?

Comment: @Diskdrive ImageSource and RandomAccessImageSource are abstract classes that can be subclassed to suit your needs. We also provide a DbImageSource tailored for databases.

Comment: So there's no built in standard ImageSource class that allow you to read from a stream or a byte[] or something? It seems like it would be a fairly common use case.

Comment: @diskdrive An image source is supposed to represent a collection of images, managed so they don't bloat memory. If you're dealing with a single image in a byte array, use a MemoryStream to make an AtalaImage and that will plug right into PdfEncoder, which accepts and ImageSource or an AtalaImage. If you've got some other custom thing, build your own ImageSource/RandomAccessImageSource - it's about 15 minutes work. For example, one of my first tests of the model was to make a TwainImageSource to pull frames from a TWAIN scanner.